# Basic Image Slider Using Hidden Image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make an image slider where I basically have images lined up horizontally (each being 700px wide and varying heights) and then using JQuery to animate a sliding right or left 700px in order to show the next image. I'm very new at jQuery and am not sure what my next step is and what my CSS should like like in order to make this work.

**jQuery**

```
$("#slideRight").click(function() {
$("#slider").animate({right:700});
});

$("#slideLeft").click(function() {
$("#slider").animate({left:700});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideButtons">
<input type="button" value="next L" id="slideLeft" />
<input type="button" value="next R" id="slideRight" />
</div>

<div id="slider">
<img src="slideTest.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="slideTest2.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="slideTest3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slider {
height: auto;
width: 700px;
position: relative;
background-color: blue; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?  Try Nivo slider or the other 9999 sliders on the market.

Comment: Since I am new to JQuery, I would really like to be able to create these things on my own so I understand how the code works and how it's written, instead of just throwing someone's else's code into my project. I'm  just looking for some advice on where my syntax might be off, or if I'm using anything wrong. Any advice helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in building an image slider here is the way that I could build soon .

NOTE : - I have used hide and show method to achieve slider there are many ways using which you can achieve . Please follow the logic instead of directly using the code .

Logic is simple

1. generate images with ids with values set to consecutive integers
2. Make all images as hidden by setting the property display none
3. make the first element visible
4. then when the next button is clicked check whether you are at the last image and display the first image if so , if not display the next image
5. to find the next image you can get the current visible image id and add 1 to that to get the next consecutive image
6. similarly for previous you can subtract to display the previous image
7. while displaying previous image you have to check whether you are viewing the first image if so display the last image . else display the previous image by calculating the id as per step 6

here is the sample rough code which I tried to build for this question , ( not tested )

```
// First make the first image visible 
$(".slide-content img:first-child").show();

// Bind the click handler 
$("#slideRight").click(function() {

// if there is only one image in the slider then return false 
if($(".slide-content > img").length == 1)
{
    return false;

}

// Set current to the visible element 
var current = $(".slide-content > img:visible").attr('id');

// hide the visible element 
$('#'+current).hide();


if(current == $(".slide-content > img").length ) 
{
    current = 1;    
}
else
{
    current = parseInt(current)+1;  
}

$('#'+current).show();


});

$("#slideLeft").click(function() {
if($(".slide-content > img").length == 1)
{
    return false;

}

var current = $(".slide-content  > img:visible").attr('id');
$('#'+current).hide();
if(current == 1) 
{
    current = $(".slide-content > img").length; 
}
else
{
    current = parseInt(current)-1;  
}

$('#'+current).show();


});

<div id="slideButtons">
<input type="button" value="next L" id="slideLeft" />
<input type="button" value="next R" id="slideRight" />
</div>

<div class="slide-content">
<img id = '1' src="slideTest.jpg" alt="" />
<img id = '2' src="slideTest2.jpg" alt="" />
<img id = '3' src="slideTest3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: That code was really helpful! I made a few tweeks and it seems to be working great in Dreamweaver when I check the code live, but not in a browser (Safari, Chrome or Firefox) when I want to check it. Any idea why? Is that a common problem...?

Comment: Also- I realized that and id can't start with a number- so if I make the ids on my images a, b, c,... how is that going to throw off the jquery? Do I then need to change the variable named "current"?

Comment: That is not the the problem , safari treats the visibility in a different way , the whole application is completely dependent on the visibility attribute ,

Comment: I tested in mozilla ,some of its versions encourage ids to be numbers , but still you can make a class as number and change "#" to "." in places where ever you are referring to ids